# Jquery each() seem to not work in my case

Tags: jquery, each

I have a list of users/websites and each of them have a banner. I want to show that banner via a tooltip.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $(".test").each(function(i) {  

          var banner_url = $("input[name='banner_url']").val();

          var index = i + 1;
          $(this).tipTip({maxWidth: "auto", edgeOffset: 10, content: banner_url + index});
     });
});
```

But it always show the same banner on each tooltip
(`index` var is just there to test the `each`, and it works, but `banner_url` not )

I've also tried to put the banner url var before `.test each()`, but with the same results. Anyone know whats up? I am sure I miss something.

```
<div class="banner">
<input type="hidden" name="banner_url" value="{$banner_url}" />
<a href="{$url}" onclick="out('{$username}');" id="{$username}" class="test" title="">{$title}</a>
</div>
```

Tried also to put those 2 into a div container, but it doesnt seem to make a difference

I can put the banner code into the title attribute, but I want to avoid having to hard code an `img` into title tag.

Thanks for any tips, help.
Seb

Comment: Can you please show the HTML structure as well? I assume the container has the class "test", and the within is a single input named "banner_url"?

Comment: Its there now. had dome issues.

Comment: I had fixed it already, to remove the code tags - you should indent your code by 4 spaces instead of using the code tags.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the whole HTML, I'm guessing you want the banner_url inside each container .test, so:

```
$(".test").each(function(i, element_with_class_test) {  
      var banner_url = $(element_with_class_test).find("input[name='banner_url']").val();
 ...
});
```

Otherwise you're always searching for the *first* input with that name, starting from the document root, and of course will always get the same value.

Comment: I would even recommend the use of `$(.test).each(function(i,e){ var url = $(e).prev('input[name="banner_url"]') ... });` since the anchor is not a container, but is the root of the search.

Comment: Brad on your example $(.test).each(function(i,e){ 
var url = $(e).prev('input[name="banner_url"]') 
... }); what is the i and the e

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with your use of:

```
$("input[name='banner_url']")
```

Calling jQuery with that selector is scoped to the document, not the element which you're picking up with each().

In your html, the  tag with the url is at the same level in the DOM as your  element, so you need to use the appropriate jQuery search function to locate it. This should work:

```
var banner_url = $(this).prevUntil("input[name='banner_url']").last().val();
```

Comment: With that it seem to only show the banner of the second .banner div. ( see updated html )